# Why won't PowerShell ISE let me set breakpoints when running as Administrator?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

Having [failed to get PowerGUI to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368348/why-does-f5-start-debugging-ignore-breakpoints-in-powergui) I've fallen back on PowerShell ISE. However if I run this as Administrator it won't let me set any breakpoints.

If I launch as normal (my login is a member of Administrators) all is well but because I need to script some tasks that require full administrator rights this is no good.

I have saved the script as a proper file (i.e. it's not "untitled1.ps1") but no joy.

I'm running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Strangely this doesn't seem to be a problem on my Windows 2008 R2 dev box (I'm logging in as user that is a member of Administrators then running PS ISE "As Administrator" and breakpoints are set and hit.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem with PowerShell and square brackets in folder and filenames.

Both PowerGUI and PowerShell ISE won't hit breakpoint if the script being debugged resides in a folder with `[` or `]` in the name.

Comment: Now that figures. The whole '*.[ch]' syntax is something I rarely use yet squares braces in filenames have caused me my fair share of grief too.

Comment: Also, if you haven't physically saved the file yet, then toggle breakpoint will be unavailable

Comment: I had a script in a One Drive folders and was not able to set breakpoints but I could run it. I open the same script into a folder not mapped to OneDrive and it worked. Then I switch back to the other script and also worked.

Answer (score 24):

I also faced the same issue, saving the file to a physical location enabled all debugging capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're running x64.  Is there any chance that you're running x64 ISE but have only set the execution policy away from restricted on x86 (or vice-versa).

Comment: see my answer. PowerShell has square bracket issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio Code and in my case, I was missing the powershell extension.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue because I had used other editor to make changes to the ps1 file. After opening the file with PowerShell ISE and clicking "Save" solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem even when the powershell ISE was running as administrator, saving the script to physical directory allowed me to have debug capabilities.